# Finding combinations of keys in a dict that produce a certain sum

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations

I have a `dict` like so:

```
a = {"a" : 1.04,
     "b" : 1.07,
     "c" : 10.99,
     ...}
```

I am trying to get all of the combinations of `keys` that `value` `sum` produces `x`, there can be repeating `keys`.

So for example a target of `3.12` can be a result of `["a", "a", "a"]`

And I wrote a code like so:

```
def combinations(data, target, result = [], partial_target = 0):
    if partial_target == target:
        yield result
    if partial_target >= target:
        return
    for key, value in data.items():
        yield from combinations(data, target, result + [key], partial_target + value)


list(combinations(a, 199.45))
```

But this keeps on spinning forever with no result, I edited my code after reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum). So I am not sure if it works or its just stuck in an infinite loop, and if not, if this is the optimal way to solve this problem.

Comment: Don't trust floats to work like that; I'd suggest testing whether the partial_target is _close to_ target.

Comment: PSA: Be warned of [floating point math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). It does not always behave as you'd expect.

Comment: And you should certainly avoid the mutable default value.

Comment: But if I would pass `result = None / if result == None : result = []`, each loop the `result` would be reset to be an empty list?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis No, because it will not be `None`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To speed up your calculations you could define a max_keys that defines the maximum length of your key combinations.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from math import isclose

test_dict = {
    "a" : 1.04,
     "b" : 1.07,
     "c" : 10.99,
     "d" : 1.56}

def get_target_combinations(dictionary, target, max_keys=3):
    filtered = {key: value for key, value in dictionary.items() if value < target}
    for num_combs in range(2, max_keys+1):
        combs = combinations_with_replacement(filtered.keys(), r=num_combs)
        for keys in combs:
            if isclose(sum(map(lambda x: dictionary[x], keys)), target):
                yield keys
        
        
list(get_target_combinations(test_dict, 3.12, max_keys=4))
>> [('d', 'd'), ('a', 'a', 'a')]
```

Comment: It looks like even with `max_keys = 5` and `len(dict) = 1000` it takes time. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: This quite terrible algorithmically. Vastly overproducing combinations...

Comment: This code takes 2min 13s on `len(dict) = 1000` and `max_keys = 5`

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, do not trust `float` for exact equality. You can use [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose), however:

```
import math

def combinations(data, target):
    def inner(target, pool):
        if math.isclose(0.0, target, abs_tol=0.00001):
            yield []
            return
        if target < 0:
            return
        for i, key in enumerate(pool):
            for c in inner(target - data[key], pool[i:]):
                yield c + [key]

    return inner(target, tuple(data.keys()))
```